# Access Denied exception when using google-api-java-client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use google-api-java-client for OAuth2.0 to create a simple 3rd party app to access an OAuth2.0 based webservices.

The programs breaks when I try to initialize

```
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new ApacheHttpTransport();
```

They are imported as:

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;

import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;

It is a simple Web Application Project using Google App Engine plugin inside Eclipse.

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.NetPermission getProxySelector)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:376)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:383)
    at java.net.ProxySelector.getDefault(ProxySelector.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport.newDefaultHttpClient(ApacheHttpTransport.java:157)
    at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport.(ApacheHttpTransport.java:100)
    at com.mytest.demo.TestApiDemoServlet.(TestApiDemoServlet.java:17)

I am using App Engine 1.8.4 and google-api-java-client 1.16.0-rc

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ApacheHttpTransport in the GAE environment as this is retricted. This is the reason it is failing. You need to use **UrlFetchTransport** instead and it should work. To use this you need to import the corresponding jars from this link directly and drop in your libs or jar folder-

https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-http-client-appengine